# pom.xml got undefined version of dependency in opendaylight controller dsbenchmark

Tags: eclipse, pom.xml, opendaylight

I'm starting to develop for opendaylight **controller project** and i used the **eclipse installer advanced mode** way (link of the tutorial: https://github.com/vorburger/opendaylight-eclipse-setup) to install the eclipse already with the opendaylight controller project. So when i try to run the mvn clean install i get the error :

- [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.opendaylight.yang:yang-data-impl:jar is missing. @ line 54, column 17

When i go to the pom.xml of org.opendaylight.controller.dsbenchmark i've noticed that the pom defines the yang-data-impl dependency (groupId and ArtifactId tags) but dont have the version tag, however i've tried to insert a version tag (used **2.0.0-SNAPSHOT**) but create this tag generate errors in others projects (projects of **org.opendaylight.controller.benchmark-aggregator**) and also generate another error that says the version (**2.0.0-SNAPSHOT**) cannot be found (**Missing artifact org.opendaylight.yang:yang-data-impl:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT**).

I'm newbie in opendaylight controller system and i don't know what version or what i have to do, so someone can explain what i'm doing wrong or what i need read to learn how to fix this?

*Sorry for the english i'm not fluent
*I got errors before , dependencies missing, but i've fixed manually all of them (installing all the dependencies one by one)
*For now that's the only error that i'm getting

---

The pom.xml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- vi: set et smarttab sw=4 tabstop=4: --><!--
Copyright (c) 2014 Cisco Systems, Inc. and others.  All rights reserved.

This program and the accompanying materials are made available under the
terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0 which accompanies this distribution,
and is available at http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.opendaylight.mdsal</groupId>
    <artifactId>binding-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.opendaylight.controller</groupId>
  <artifactId>dsbenchmark</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>bundle</packaging>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.opendaylight.controller</groupId>
        <artifactId>mdsal-artifacts</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.opendaylight.controller</groupId>
      <artifactId>benchmark-api</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.opendaylight.controller</groupId>
      <artifactId>sal-binding-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.opendaylight.controller</groupId>
      <artifactId>sal-core-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.opendaylight.yangtools</groupId>
      <artifactId>yang-data-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- ERROR HERE!!!! -->
      <groupId>org.opendaylight.yang</groupId>
      <artifactId>yang-data-impl</artifactId>


    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        jacoco-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [0.7.2.201409121644,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Check the settings.xml that your maven refers to, it should have reference to ODL repository.

Comment: i've checked the settings.xml and the refer repositories is the opendaylight-release and opendaylight-snapshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the [ODL Eclipse Setup FAQ](https://github.com/vorburger/opendaylight-eclipse-setup#faq), and tried all tips there?

For example, the custom Maven settings.xml which is required for it to download artifacts from http://nexus.opendaylight.org is automatically configured, but the very first time you need to restart Eclipse once.)

Do not touch any of the pom.xml - it should just work out-of-the-box, because in ODL CI all of these projects (like controller/benchmark/dsbenchmark) of course do build just fine.

Are ALL of your projects in Eclipse red, or just some?

Comment: I selected the opendaylight-release and opendaylight-snapshots profiles in the settings.xml, i think that i tried all tips in the FAQ that is related to my problem.
I restored the pom.xml file to the original (the pom.xml in this post is the original, auto-generated)
All my projects are normal, only the org.opendaylight.controller.dsbenchmark is red.

Comment: @KevinCosta Given that all but 1 project work for you, I suspected there may be something configured wrong in the pom.xml of that particular project (that has happened in the past), so I had a look at controller/benchmark/dsbenchmark (from current master branch), but it actually opens just fine without red for me, so not sure what you have hit - sorry! Sometimes you’ll have to right-click projects to do Maven > Update Projects (Alt-F5) for an explicit one-time uncheck Offline and Update Dependencies.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, i looked for some asks in your video tutorial and i found a response that helped me, but i've worked with the eclipse in a windows system, i don't know exactly if this windows system is influenciating for the failures, i've changed for an ubuntu 16.04 system and maked again the default procedures with the additional command mvn -Pq,ide clean generate-sources and it worked, the errors has been fixed

Comment: Also i've tried the command mvn -Pq,ide clean generate-sources in the windows eclipse and it don't worked

Comment: Ok then from what you are reporting here, it sounds like at least in that particular project there is some configuration in the POM which make the eclipse-setup work only on Linux and not on Windows, that's possible. The opendaylight eclipse-setup has not been much tested under Windows, I have to admit.